# How to make cluster on power BI raw data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have raw data set

```
Category    Month   Revenue Expected Result based on condition  Revenue Bucket
A   1   10  if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   more than 10
A   2   5   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   more than 10
A   3   2   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   more than 10
B   1   0   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   0
B   2   0   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   0
B   3   0   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   0
C   1   2   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   1-10
C   2   5   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   1-10
C   3   2   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   1-10
D   1   12  if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   more than 10
D   2   3   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   more than 10
D   3   2   if(sum of category is 0 then 0, else if sum of category >0 and <10 , then 1-10, else more than 10   more than 10
```

Based on the revenue condition , revenue bucket is my expected output.

My code

```
Revenue_Bucket = if(CALCULATE(SUM('Spend by Client'[Revenue]))=0,"$0",if(CALCULATE(SUM('Spend by Client'[Revenue]))<10,"$1-10","More than 0"))
```

I tried with the DAX and it is not helping me out. Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `sum of category` doesnt work because category is not numerical. A count would work but I am not sure what you whant to do there.

If you want a cluster based on your revenue column you can add on like this in dax. First add a new column and use the following dax expression:

```
= IF('Spend by Client'[Revenue] = 0; "$0"; IF('Spend by Client'[Revenue] < 10; "$1-10"; "More than 10")
```

You can nest the if´s as often as you want to cover more categories.